# When upgrading IIS a 800a0001 Request.BinaryRead fails

Tags: iis-6, web-applications

When a IIS was upgraded to IIS 6.0 or higher, large files (specifically larger than 204,800 bytes) uploaded via ASP get the following error:

> error '800a0001'
>
> Request.BinaryRead failed

What will fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IIS6 limits the file upload side to 204,800 bytes.  To increase this maximum size edit the [metabase file](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx?mfr=true) entry: **AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed**.

Set the value to the maximum size you want to allow.

ex (for a maximum of one gig):

```
AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed = "1000000000"
```

(Thanks to [Internet Software Services](http://helpdesk.inet-sciences.com/ISSSupportCustomer/ViewCase.asp?Casenum=1261&ReturnPage=FAQ))

Comment: Yes, this is a setting you should have on your check list for IIS 6, though I hope everybody will install windows server 2008 on their new machines.

Comment: Please add the equivalent for Server 2008.